# User Accounts for IOS app with Django backend

Tags: ios, django

As described in the title I am using Django as the server end for an IOS app I am building.

Lets assume theoretically that I was to reach 1 million users. Would it be more effective/efficient to build my own REST Api for user accounts on top of Django, or use something like Parse?

How would I build a scalable production-ready user account system with Django? (With user tokens and all).

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
Don't prematurely optimize.
```

You'll eventually reach 1 million users with your app, but it's always a good idea to worry about such great numbers later.

In the meantime, you need 2 apps (if you want to use oauth2):

- [API](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/api/)
- [OAUTH2 provider](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/oauth/) ([oauth-server](http://hiidef.github.io/oauth2app/), [oauth provider](https://github.com/caffeinehit/django-oauth2-provider))

You'll then have to wire all together. This [blogpost](http://ianalexandr.com/blog/building-a-true-oauth-20-api-with-django-and-tasty-pie.html) is a good starting point.